# Eclipse: the import javacard cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, javacard

I'm relatively new to eclipse and I need to develop a Javacard Application. I got eclipse neon and JDK8 + Java card developement Kit. I've done all the tutorial installation untill this page (included) https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/guide/eclipse_java_card_plug-in.htm#JCUGC127 but when I import a project sample from the javacard directory it tells me (for example for Hello World one):

```
APDU cannot be resolved to a type   
HelloWorld.java /HelloWorld/applet/src/com/sun/jcclassic/samples/helloworld line 65 Java Problem
Applet cannot be resolved to a type HelloWorld.java /HelloWorld/applet/src/com/sun/jcclassic/samples/helloworld line 29 Java Problem
ISO7816 cannot be resolved to a variable    HelloWorld.java /HelloWorld/applet/src/com/sun/jcclassic/samples/helloworld line 69 Java Problem
ISO7816 cannot be resolved to a variable    HelloWorld.java /HelloWorld/applet/src/com/sun/jcclassic/samples/helloworld line 70 Java Problem
ISO7816 cannot be resolved to a variable    HelloWorld.java /HelloWorld/applet/src/com/sun/jcclassic/samples/helloworld line 78 Java Problem
ISO7816 cannot be resolved to a variable    HelloWorld.java /HelloWorld/applet/src/com/sun/jcclassic/samples/helloworld line 80 Java Problem
The import javacard cannot be resolved  HelloWorld.java /HelloWorld/applet/src/com/sun/jcclassic/samples/helloworld line 20 Java Problem
The import javacard cannot be resolved  HelloWorld.java /HelloWorld/applet/src/com/sun/jcclassic/samples/helloworld line 21 Java Problem
The import javacard cannot be resolved  HelloWorld.java /HelloWorld/applet/src/com/sun/jcclassic/samples/helloworld line 22 Java Problem
The import javacard cannot be resolved  HelloWorld.java /HelloWorld/applet/src/com/sun/jcclassic/samples/helloworld line 23 Java Problem
The import javacard cannot be resolved  HelloWorld.java /HelloWorld/applet/src/com/sun/jcclassic/samples/helloworld line 24 Java Problem
The method register() is undefined for the type HelloWorld  HelloWorld.java /HelloWorld/applet/src/com/sun/jcclassic/samples/helloworld line 38 Java Problem
Util cannot be resolved HelloWorld.java /HelloWorld/applet/src/com/sun/jcclassic/samples/helloworld line 78 Java Problem
```

And I got similar output with the other projects. I tried some "solutions" i googled like cleaning the project,etc but no one solved the issue. I'd appreciate some tips of what might be happening and what do I have to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add api_xxx.jar to your project "Java build path";
The library "api_xxx.jar" is located at JCKit_Dir/lib/.